# Space after symbol with JS Intl

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, number-formatting, ecmascript-intl

I want to format a currency with [NumberFormat of Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) and get the returned value with a space " " between the symbol and the number.

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(12345)
// "US$12.345,00"
new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }).format(12345)
// "R$12.345,00"
```

What I want: "US$ 12.345,00", "R$ 12.345,00"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18):

You can use `replace` to further format the currency.

```js
var usd = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(12345).replace(/^(\D+)/, '$1 ');

var euro = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(12345).replace(/^(\D+)/, '$1 ');
var deEuro = new Intl.NumberFormat('de', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(12345).replace(/^(\D+)/, '$1 ');


console.log(usd);
console.log(euro);
console.log(deEuro);
```

### Update

There is currently an [issue](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/issues/221) with Intl.js where some browsers put a space between the currency and the value resulting in the output that OP wanted. In that case, the formatting above will result in 2 spaces (as seen in the comments below).

You can add on `.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` to replace multiple spaces with a single space. This will ensure that if a space was added by the browser due to the above issue, the final output will still have a single space as expected.

```js
var usd = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(12345).replace(/^(\D+)/, '$1 ').replace(/\s+/, ' ');

var euro = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(12345).replace(/^(\D+)/, '$1 ').replace(/\s+/, ' ');
var deEuro = new Intl.NumberFormat('de', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(12345).replace(/^(\D+)/, '$1 ').replace(/\s+/, ' ');


console.log(usd);
console.log(euro);
console.log(deEuro);
```

Comment: Notice that `'$'` as second argument in String#replace has special meaning.

Comment: @RobG I updated my answer to take different currencies into account.

Comment: Does the currency always come before the number?

Comment: @John Hascall Good point.  Was assuming currencies before number here.

Comment: @JohnHascall—do you have an example where it doesn't?

Comment: I don't, but I also didn't see that the function specified that it always did, so I wondered ...

Comment: @JohnHascall—Ok, used [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbol): "*The Cape Verdean escudo places its symbol in the decimal separator position (e.g., 20$00). The usage of many European countries, such as France, Germany, Scandinavian countries, is to place the symbol after the amount 20,50 €.*".

Comment: Thank @ChavaG! But I wanted a more graceful way. With replace, we can do it: .replace(/^(\D+)/, '$1 ')
It attends only if the symbol appears before the number.

Comment: For me, this outputs two spaces: `US$  12.345,00`, `€  12.345,00` and `12.345,00 €`.

Comment: This seems to be due to a known issue where some browsers put a space between the currency and the value as seen [here](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/issues/221). In those browsers, this code will add an additional space. You can add `.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` after the original formatting to replace any multiple spaces with a single space. This will ensure that if a space was already added by the browser due to the above issue, you will still be left with a single space.

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(formatPrice(1200, 'en-US', 'USD'));
console.log(formatPrice(1200, 'fr-FR', 'EUR'));
  
 
function formatPrice(value, locale, currency) {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, { style: 'currency', currency })
    .format(value)
    // if the price begins with digit, place the space after the digit
    .replace(/^([\d,.]+)/, '$1 ')
    // if the price ends with digit, place the space before the digit
    .replace(/([\d,.]+)$/, ' $1') 
}
```

Comment: This question already has a highly upvoted answer. Can you edit your answer to explain what your code does and how it differs from the other answer?

Comment: @MichaelM. The comments in the code explain the contribution, but I agree that this should be elaborated on in the rest of the answer (outside of the code snippet)

Answer (score 0):

```
 "use client";
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  value: any; // your type
  className?: string;
}

function Currency({ value, className }: Props) {
  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-IN", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "INR",

    maximumFractionDigits: 3,
  });
  const [symbol, ...others] = formatter.formatToParts(value);
  return (
   



<span className={`flex items-center ${className}`}>
      <span className="currency">{symbol.value} </span>
      <span className="ml-2">{others.map(({ value }) => value).join("")}</span>
    </span>




  );
}

export default Currency;
```

This approach worked for me :)