# Intl.NumberFormat returns a result where number and currency symbol are divided through spacing

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I just added a filter for my vue-app that is supposed to format a value as currency in EUR (German format).

This is the function:

```
app.config.globalProperties.$filters = {
    currency(value) {
        return new Intl.NumberFormat(process.env.MIX_LOCALE, { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(value);
    },
}
```

If I now do something like

```
{{$filters.currency(17.85)}}
```

I am getting this result: `17,85 €`

As you can see, the value and the currency symbol are divided through a space. This is not quite what we are used to see in Germany, we would expect `17,85€`.

As I did not find anything helpful in the docs to `Intl.NumberFormat` I am wondering if the removal of the space is even possible with `Intl.NumberFormat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first reaction was, why not `replace()`? Then I saw the other answer's link. Then I tried it and the regex didn't work, the space was still there. So here's a working replace to fix the bug.

```
app.config.globalProperties.$filters = {
    currency(value) {
        return new Intl.NumberFormat(
           process.env.MIX_LOCALE, 
           {style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'})
           .format(value).replace(/\s/g,'');
    }
}
```

Testable snippet

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(1234567).replace(/\s/g,''));
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in this [ticket here](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/issues/221), the issue is known to Intl, and it is still open.

What you can do is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533919/space-after-symbol-with-js-intl).